# MAAS JUJU bootstrap problems

Tags: juju, maas, openstack

I have MAAS setup and configured with with the nodes listed in the ready state.
I then proceed to bootstrap JUJU and after the timeout period receive a bootstrap error. Here are the log files of the error. Has anyone had this error? and or what am i doing wrong?

Thanks in Advance

```
[INFO: 09-10 20:43:27, openstack-install:183] Starting OpenStack Installer v0.99.22
[INFO: 09-10 20:43:27, openstack-install:184] Start command: ['/usr/bin/openstack-install']
[INFO: 09-10 20:43:27, openstack-install:195] Creating juju directories: /home/mlbarnes/.cloud-in                                                            stall/juju
[INFO: 09-10 20:43:30, openstack-install:245] Running Kilo release
[INFO: 09-10 20:43:47, installbase.py:133] Performing a Landscape OpenStack Autopilot install
[DEBUG: 09-10 20:44:34, landscape.py:71] Existing MAAS defined, doing a LDS installation with exi                                                            sting MAAS.
[DEBUG: 09-10 20:44:50, utils.py:336] 0
[DEBUG: 09-10 20:44:50, utils.py:644] ssh keys exist for this user, they will be used instead.
[DEBUG: 09-10 20:44:50, multi.py:124] Bootstrapping Juju: JUJU_HOME=/home/mlbarnes/.cloud-install                                                            /juju juju  bootstrap
[DEBUG: 09-10 21:45:20, multi.py:130] Problem during bootstrap: '{'output': '', 'status': 1, 'err                                                            ': 'Bootstrapping environment "maas"\nStarting new instance for initial state server\nLaunching i                                                            nstance\nWARNING no architecture was specified, acquiring an arbitrary node\n - /MAAS/api/1.0/nod                                                            es/node-438c6572-559e-11e5-a407-000c29d64d7b/\nInstalling Juju agent on bootstrap instance\nWaiti                                                            ng for address\nAttempting to connect to MAAS02.maas:22\nAttempting to connect to MAAS02.maas:22\                                                            nAttempting to connect to 10.1.1.151:22\nERROR failed to bootstrap environment: waited for 1h0m0s                                                             without being able to connect: ssh: connect to host 10.1.1.151 port 22: No route to host\n'}'
[DEBUG: 09-10 21:45:20, utils.py:56] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/utils.py", line 71, in run
    super().run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/threading.py", line 868, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/machinewait.py", line 129, in do_continue
    self.installer.do_install()
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/controllers/install/multi.py", line 131, in do_install
    raise Exception("Problem with juju bootstrap.")
Exception: Problem with juju bootstrap.

[INFO: 09-10 22:00:04, ev.py:100] Stopping eventloop
[INFO: 09-10 22:00:04, utils.py:84] Cleanup, saving latest config object.
[DEBUG: 09-10 22:00:04, utils.py:90] Attempting to reset the terminal
[INFO: 09-10 22:57:56, openstack-install:183] Starting OpenStack Installer v0.99.22
[INFO: 09-10 22:57:56, openstack-install:184] Start command: ['/usr/bin/openstack-install']
[INFO: 09-10 22:57:56, openstack-install:195] Creating juju directories: /home/mlbarnes/.cloud-in                                                            stall/juju
[INFO: 09-10 22:57:58, openstack-install:245] Running Kilo release
[INFO: 09-10 22:58:28, installbase.py:133] Performing a Landscape OpenStack Autopilot install
[DEBUG: 09-10 22:59:07, landscape.py:71] Existing MAAS defined, doing a LDS installation with exi                                                            sting MAAS.
[DEBUG: 09-10 22:59:12, utils.py:336] 0
[DEBUG: 09-10 22:59:12, utils.py:644] ssh keys exist for this user, they will be used instead.
[DEBUG: 09-10 22:59:12, multi.py:124] Bootstrapping Juju: JUJU_HOME=/home/mlbarnes/.cloud-install                                                            /juju juju  bootstrap
[DEBUG: 09-10 23:59:42, multi.py:130] Problem during bootstrap: '{'status': 1, 'err': 'Bootstrapp                                                            ing environment "maas"\nStarting new instance for initial state server\nLaunching instance\nWARNI                                                            NG no architecture was specified, acquiring an arbitrary node\n - /MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-438c65                                                            72-559e-11e5-a407-000c29d64d7b/\nInstalling Juju agent on bootstrap instance\nWaiting for address                                                            \nAttempting to connect to MAAS02.maas:22\nAttempting to connect to MAAS02.maas:22\nAttempting to                                                             connect to 10.1.1.151:22\nERROR failed to bootstrap environment: waited for 1h0m0s without being                                                             able to connect: ssh: connect to host 10.1.1.151 port 22: No route to host\n', 'output': ''}'
[DEBUG: 09-10 23:59:42, utils.py:56] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/utils.py", line 71, in run
    super().run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/threading.py", line 868, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/machinewait.py", line 129, in do_continue
    self.installer.do_install()
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/controllers/install/multi.py", line 131, in do_install
    raise Exception("Problem with juju bootstrap.")
Exception: Problem with juju bootstrap.

[INFO: 09-11 00:04:21, utils.py:84] Cleanup, saving latest config object.
[DEBUG: 09-11 00:04:21, utils.py:90] Attempting to reset the terminal
```

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a timeout in waiting for the machine to become reachable.

Does the MAAS02.maas hostname resolve to the IP address of the machine in question?  If so, is it reachable via ping and/or ssh?

For example:

```
host MAAS02.maas
MAAS02.maas has address x.x.x.x

nc -vz MAAS02.maas 22
Connection to MAAS02.maas 22 port [tcp/ssh] succeeded!
```

Please also be sure to use the [current stable Juju version](https://launchpad.net/~juju/+archive/ubuntu/stable).

Comment: Ok so i went into MAAS and was able to aquire the node and place the node into "Deployed" status.

Comment: the pxe provided me ip address 10.1.1.151 i was able to nslookup and host and got the ip address above.  when running the command nc -vx MAAS02.maas i got nc: connect to MAAS02.maas port 22 (tcp) failed: No route to host

Comment: When i got these types of errors, it was because the machine times were not synced.  That lead to all kinds of weird and wonderful errors.  I wrote an script that ssh'd into the remote machines and performed:

    sudo ntpdate <ntp server IP>